# My search query doesnt work and displays the following error, :TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter, syntax-error

Here is my search method, it doesnt work please help me fix this.

```
def Search():
    Database()
    name=str(SEARCH.get())
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE "%str(SEARCH.get())%"")
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline 3, You have already converted the input to string and saved its value to variable `name`, So why are you converting it again?
And use of formatted strings is better.
It can be like this,

> cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE {name}")